# Hiding pivot table field using a button

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, pivot-table

I have a pivot table in Microsoft Excel 2010 with several row and column labels. For the sake of user friendliness I would like to have several movable, clickable buttons which each hides/shows one of the row or column labels from the pivot table without having to use the Field List, similar to how I already have slicers with buttons for filtering. Is this possible?

To clarify, I don't want to *filter* the table, just decide whether the columns/rows for the different column/row labels are shown at all. It is important that the layout of the pivot table is not changed after hiding and reshowing.

For example, I would like to be able to use two buttons, one for "Legs" and one for "species" to change the following table:

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

Into the following:

[image: Screenshot]

... and back.

Edit: Something like [this](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/799629-hide-show-columns-pivot-table-excel-2010-a.html) perhaps? But referring to the field names, not column letters.

Edit 2: For my actual file, but not the simplified example shown above, it seems  something similar can be accomplished using the "expand and collapse" function, but that leaves the columns still visible (though looking empty). Ideally I would liked the columns to disappear.

Edit 3: Here is another screenshot which looks a bit more like my actual table:

[image: Screenshot]

Note that if I uncheck any of the row labels from the Fields Section of the Field List and recheck it, the order will be different from before. That's a problem. Ideally I would want to specify that row label "version" should always come after row label "code" (which is permanently shown) and before row label "title" (if it is shown) and that row label "title" should always be the last row label if it is shown. I would also like to be able to hide/reshow row labels "version" and "title" individually, using a button for each.